# How do I ignore a file that already exists?

Tags: python, file

This is what I have:

```
import os

names = ['Abby','Betty','Bella','Peter','Jack','Sonya']
file_path = rf'../database/{names}'
if os.path.exists(file_path) == True:
   print('name folders exists')
else:
   for name in names:
      os.makedirs(os.path.join('../database', name))
```

I want the code to create the folders for each name in `names` list if they do not exist and print `name folder exists` if they already exist. But I keep getting a `FileExistsError` on the last line. Can someone tell me what I should change in the code to get it to work in the way I want it to?

Comment: `file_path` is a *single* path name, not a list of individual path names.

Answer (score 2):

Where you went wrong was line 3. This line doesn't do what you think it would do:

```
file_path = rf'../database/{names}'
```

It creates a single string with all the names added as a list.
Instead, you can try something like this:

```
import os
names = ['Abby','Betty','Bella','Peter','Jack','Sonya']
base_path = '../database'
for name in names:
    full_path = os.path.join(base_path, name)
    if os.path.exists(full_path):
        print('name folders exists')
    else:
        os.mkdir(full_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the new (introduced in Python 3.4-3.5, so not that new now) [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module instead of `os.path`:

```
from pathlib import Path

names = ['Abby','Betty','Bella','Peter','Jack','Sonya']
BASE_PATH = Path('../database')

for name in names:
    (BASE_PATH / name).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) of `pathlib.Path.mkdir`:

> If `exist_ok` is true, `FileExistsError` exceptions will be ignored, but only if the last path component is not an existing non-directory file.

Answer (score 0):

use a `try/except` block to catch and ignore these errors.

eg

```
try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join('../database', name))
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

You could even rewrite your code like this:

```
import os
names = ['Abby','Betty','Bella','Peter','Jack','Sonya']

for name in names:
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join('../database', name))
    except FileExistsError:
        print('name folders exists')
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. You really saved me here in my coding project.

Comment: That does not work because the result of file_path is `../database/['Abby','Betty','Bella','Peter','Jack','Sonya']`

Comment: @Siscall good catch, `file_path` isn't actually doing anything here though so it should still work. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Lil_coder: If you add an `exists_ok=True` keyword argument to [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) calls using `try`/`except` like this would not be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your `file_path` variable is wrong. It concatenate `../database/` with your list. All elements of your list. The result looks like this:

```py
names = ['Abby','Betty','Bella','Peter','Jack','Sonya']
file_path = rf'../database/{names}'
print(file_path)
# ../database/['Abby', 'Betty', 'Bella', 'Peter', 'Jack', 'Sonya']
```

Instead, do like this:

```py
# Import os + define names

for name in names:
    path = rf'../database/{name}'
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path))
```

**PS:** line 3: `if os.path.exists(file_path) == True` The `== True` is not necessary because the exists function returns a boolean. Just do `if os.path.exists(file_path):`

Answer (score 0):

**Example, just to see how IGNORE files or words works:**

```
def save_to_pdf(directory_path):
    modified_files = []
    file_count = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
        for file_name in files:
            if file_name.endswith(".html"):

                # ignora fisierele care contin 'webinar' in numele lor
                if "webinar" in file_name:
                    print(f"Fișierul {file_name} conține 'webinar' în numele său și va fi ignorat.")
                    continue

                file_path = root + os.sep + file_name
                file_content = read_text_from_file(file_path)

                # ignora fisierele care contin 'https://pastebin.com' in continutul lor
                if "https://pastebin.com" in file_content:
                    print(f"Fișierul {file_name} conține 'https://pastebin.com' în conținutul său și va fi ignorat.")
                    continue
```